# Boost Serialization : Does the default constructor have to be public?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

Just a tid bit of information that doesn't seem documented anywhere. Does anyone know? Because I would like to make it private, hoping that the constructor would be called from `boost::serialization::access` which is declared as a friend.

Comment: I think it should be ok with the `boost::serialization::access`. Did you try it?

Comment: This kind of thing is easily determined by just trying it.

Comment: @Seth Absolutely, I fully agree. And then afterwards reporting the result to the world.

Comment: Nah, its so quick that when anyone needs to know, they can just try for themselves. Or better yet, just program as if you didn't care, and then fix it when you get an error :)

Comment: @Seth: I disagree. I believe it should be part of the doc, to me it was a hassle to try, I believe google-ing it in 10 secs is faster than coding it up for anyone and if I feel that way, chances are, at least one other person does. Even if it would have been me trying it, and I would have if noone else would have known the answer, I do believe this information to be worth being on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test example. Given that this works I'd assume it is a feature and would be upset if there was a future release that didn't allow the access granting mechanism to grant access to private default constructors.

```
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

struct Colour {
    double colour[4];
    boost::shared_ptr<Colour> alt;
    static boost::shared_ptr<Colour> test() {
       return boost::shared_ptr<Colour>(new Colour);
    }
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int /*file_version*/) {
        ar & colour;
    }

    Colour() {
        std::cout << "Getting called" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    boost::shared_ptr<Colour> c = Colour::test();
    c->alt = Colour::test();

    std::cout << "Created" << std::endl;

    std::stringstream str;
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(str);
    oa & c;

    std::cout << "Saved" << std::endl;

    c.reset();

    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(str);
    ia & c;

    std::cout << "Restored" << std::endl;
}
```

(Interestingly it seems to default construct one and then copy construct another on my system).